# How to use external resource file in the WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, resources

My projects have a resource file each. (.resx)

I wanted to integrate the resources of all projects because it looks complicated. So I created a project for only resources by integrating resources of all projects.

Now all projects referenced this resource project and I trying to access the resource of the resource project from other projects but it was impossible.

I want to know how to use the resource of the external project.
Could someone tell me a solution?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Could you please explain, what problem do you have and what have you tried to solve it? This point _I wanted to integrate the resources of all projects because it looks complicated_ isn't clear. What is complicated? By default all localization resources are compiled into separate satellite assembly and linked to the main assembly using assembly linker

Comment: Previous each project had resources each. many resource content duplicated and it look complicated. so I wanted to integrate resources to remove duplication.

Comment: but after integrate, I faced the above problem. Is my idea stupid? Is it best roll back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your resource access modifier to the public!